# Assist find if a user input number is a prime number or not using for loop in Java. Its easy to do it with a While Loop but am unable to figure for

Tags: java, for-loop

> I am unable to break out of the loop, when I use the combo of for loop and if case.

Comment: HI.  Please take the [tour], read [ask], and post a [mcve].  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `java` method that says if an `integer` is prime, returning `true` if yes and `false` if not.
During the interaction of `for` it checks if any number divides n and results in the remainder 0. If so, it means that the number is not prime.

```
public boolean isPrime(int number){
    if(number < 2) return false;
    else if(number == 2) return true;

    boolean isPrime = true;

    for(int i = 2; i < number; i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}
```